# AWS - Amazon.Extensions.S3.Encryption.AmazonS3EncryptionClientBase is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sitecore, aws-sdk

While implementing AWS client side encryption created object of `AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2` which implements `AmazonS3EncryptionClientBase`. In local everything working fine but when uploaded on server it is giving following exception

```
Message: Type 'Amazon.Extensions.S3.Encryption.AmazonS3EncryptionClientBase' from assembly 'Amazon.Extensions.S3.Encryption, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface.
```

Other dll's version as follows,

```
Amazon.Extensions.S3.Encryption - 1.2.1
AWSSDK.Core -3.5.2
AWSSDK.KeyManagementService -3.5.2.2
AWSSDK.S3 - 3.5.7.8
```

Also tried with upgrading dll's, still getting same issue

```
Message: Type 'Amazon.Extensions.S3.Encryption.AmazonS3EncryptionClientBase' from assembly 'Amazon.Extensions.S3.Encryption, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface.
```

Dll versions for above one

```
Amazon.Extensions.S3.Encryption - 2.1.0
AWSSDK.Core - 3.7.300.3
AWSSDK.KeyManagementService - 3.7.300.3
AWSSDK.S3 - 3.7.300.3
```

to create client

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2(PublicKey, SecretKey, config, EncryptionMaterials))
                {
                    client.PutObject(putobject);
                }
```

Comment: I don't understand - what's 'Other dll's version'? The code works locally but doesn't on the server? Can you tell us more about the server? .NET 8? Framework? Self hosted? Can you please provide the full list of packages